# naming the result of a case when in hive

Tags: hive, case, hiveql, case-when

I am very new to hive.  With my case statement, I am trying to create a variable called period that is zero during one time period and one during another, but I get a 'cannot recognize input' error.  How do I name the result of a case expression in hive?  It will name itself `_c7` or something like that, but then I have problems using this `_c7` variable in the next step (eof error).

```
CREATE TABLE abc.temp2 AS 
            SELECT a.*,
case 
when to_date(date)>='2016-07-01' and to_date(date)<'2017-07-01' then 0 
when to_date(date)>='2017-07-01' and to_date(date)<'2018-07-01' then 1
else null 
end **as period,**
array_contains(z,'abc') as abc,
array_contains(z,'def') as def
FROM abc.temp a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `case` statement within a set of parenthesis.

```
CREATE TABLE abc.temp2 AS 
            SELECT a.*,
(case 
when to_date(date)>='2016-07-01' and to_date(date)<'2017-07-01' then 0 
when to_date(date)>='2017-07-01' and to_date(date)<'2018-07-01' then 1
else null 
end) as period,
array_contains(z,'abc') as abc,
array_contains(z,'def') as def
FROM abc.temp a;
```